# What are the responsibilities of a game engine, and which of these things need to especially be efficient?

Tags: architecture, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should a game engine do?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/what-should-a-game-engine-do)

What are the usual responsibilities of a game engine, and which of these things especially need to be efficient (performance-wise)?

Can I get a break-down of the purposes that a game engine is used to serve, and how it differs from a *game* itself? I'm a newb, so some intuitive things may need to be explained.... Thanks! :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this topic already.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/859/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-a-game-engine  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/the-game-vs-the-game-engine http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/what-should-a-game-engine-do