# Beginner - Need help with API's etc for video game in C++

Tags: c++

I’m trying to program my first actual good video game that will be an FPS. I’m a beginner at C++ and I have messed with OpenGL a little. I have two parts to this question:

- What graphics pipeline API should I use (OpenGL, Vulkan, DirectX)? I would like this game to be able to work on PC and Mac (also hopefully) Xbox.
- What does a game engine really do? Do I need one?

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.se! Unfortunately, the two other questions you asked (What graphics pipeline API should I use? and Do I need one?) are considered off-topic here because they are based on opinions.

Comment: Uh, oh. I guess that is opinion based. I'll make my questions less opinion based in the future

Comment: "What does a game engine really do?" -isn't opinion based, is on topic & we happen to have [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8488/33287) which covers that pretty well. Whether or not you need one is a question only you can answer & it basically comes down to what your priorities are - do you want/need to program the infrastructure or have one provided to you?