# Is GLUT obsolete?

Tags: opengl, glut

A question was [asked about good, up-to date OpenGL resources](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl), [one of the answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1189/5371) was a link to a tutorial about modern OpenGL programming.

The tutorial in question uses GLUT and GLEW, but I have read somewhere that GLUT is obsolete. Is that true?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is GLUT 3.7 out of date? Absolutely. You should *never* use it for *anything*.

However, [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) is perfectly fine to use. It is 100% backwards compatible with GLUT 3.7. FreeGLUT is a good utility to have when you need to slap together a quick and dirty program.

Comment: I upvoted. Nonetheless, as I am fascinated with computing history, I would like to play with the same rules the programmers had back then, so I would use a WinXP VM, VS2005, and GLUT, just in this pandemic times.

Answer (score 7):

There is freeglut now :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeglut

[freeglut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeglut)

Answer (score 5):

Even though the original GLUT is not in active development anymore, its still a good tool for its targeted domain, which is quick OpenGL testing and demos. It was *never* intended to be a framework for developing complex OpenGL programs.

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit

> The two aims of GLUT are to allow the creation of rather portable code
>   between operating systems (GLUT is cross-platform) and to make
>   learning OpenGL easier. Getting started with OpenGL programming while
>   using GLUT often takes only a few lines of code and does not require
>   knowledge of operating system–specific windowing APIs.

So no, if you use it for quick OpenGL tests, demos and learning, then it is *not* obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

Yes GLUT is obsolete and not under developement since 1998 with the release of the 3.7 version.

From French Wikipedia:

> La bibliothèque GLUT n'est désormais plus en développement et s'est arrêtée à la version 3.7 en mai 1998.

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_utility_toolkit

Edit:

Sorry for the french reference but i haven't find any date on the english wikipedia. The translation is:

> The GLUT library is no longer in development and stopped at version 3.7 in May 1998.

And the link to the english wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit

Comment: And even if it wasn't obsolete, it was never meant for production code.

Comment: you could use English wiki for reference!

Comment: The french wiki page contains no references - that date could be completely made up

Comment: Here the release note of GLUT 3.7 dated of 7 may 1998 : http://freeware.sgi.com/Installable/glut-3.7.html. And here freeglut sourceforge webpage saying GLUT was abandonned in 1998 : http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

Comment: -1 for being wrong. GLUT 3.7 may be out of date, but FreeGLUT is *not*.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, i think i've badly written my previous comment. By giving a link to the FreeGlut web page i wasn't saying that FreeGlut is outdated. I wanted to show the section "Why?" of the article where the author was saying that GLUT latest version was released in 1998. FreeGlut isn't outdated and represents a better alternative to GLUT.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at GLFW: http://www.glfw.org/

It's a very easy to use cross-platform API that is still in development and has good documentation!

All it does, is to create an OpenGL context and provide means to get input (+ some extra features like threading)