# OpenGL Learning Material (that's up to date)

Tags: opengl, books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good learning resources for OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl)
>   [Good resources for learning modern OpenGL (3.0 or later)?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/good-resources-for-learning-modern-opengl-3-0-or-later)

So im sure there are topics on this, but alot of them list older material. And the last book:
[http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-SuperBible-Comprehensive-Tutorial-Reference/dp/0321712617/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1346116133&sr=8-1&keywords=opengl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321712617)

REALLY REALLY disappointed me. I DO NOT want to use someone else's library to learn this stuff, that bothers me SOOO much.

So I was hoping there was a newer book that goes into detail, and doesn't use some sort of library "Hiding" everything from you.

Or should I just look at older material? If so....anything thats not "too" out of date. Terrain tutorials are a plus (that's kinda my "goal").

Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked [plenty](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl) of [times](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/good-resources-for-learning-modern-opengl-3-0-or-later) already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very few.  Here are the only two I know of, one of which is still quite incomplete.

This first one is slowly becoming the "de facto" OpenGL tutorial.

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

This second one is only several chapters in with no updates in a while, but hopefully if enough people pester the author he'll keep working on it.  I found the writing style to be pretty good for a technical topic.

http://openglbook.com/

Comment: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/877/should-i-answer-questions-that-do-not-belong-here